# “Something big” in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

I want to say, “Something big is happening today.” Is the following translation the most appropriate?

**Algo grande va a pasar hoy.**

In the same vein, is the following the correct translation for, “Something big fell to the floor.”?

**Algo grande cayó al suelo.**

If there are any regional differences, please elaborate that too, Mexican in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that `something big` is perfectly translateable as `algo importante`. However `algo grande` is also a good way to say it. Then:

```
Something big is happening today
```

Could be:

```
Algo grande va a ocurrir hoy
Algo importante va a ocurrir hoy
```

However, I remember this `something big` in some other kind of sentences that try to give more importance to the first part of the sentence. Like adding `about to happen`:

```
Algo grande está a punto de ocurrir
```

Which translates to be:

```
Something big is about to hapen
```

If we literally translate `Something big fell to the floor` then it should be (If it has another sense please tell):

```
Algo grande cayó al suelo
```

Comment: http://youtu.be/thl6buL-vG0

Answer (score 1):

If I had to say the way that sentence would be said in Spain, I'd go for:

`Hoy va a pasar algo grande`

I think that'd the usual ordering of the words. I can't say for how they would say in other spanish-speaking countries.

However, there are other words that you could use depending on the tone you want to achieve.

You could go for `importante`, if it's a serious thing, `gordo`, which even though the word is usually informal, can be used for grave matters...

For your second sentence, the translation you proposed is correct. It's a much more straightforward sentence.

Comment: There's no way more correct than other but it's true that usually the time adverb is placed next to the verb. However, if what you want is give emphasis to `something big`, then `today` should be placed at the end of the sentence. I like your answer, but I would point that `gordo` is a very informal word.

Comment: Yes, I only meant that was the usual order in Spain, don't know enough about the way in the other spanish-speaking countries. 

And yes, gordo is very informal. Actually, i'm going to edit the sentence to reflect that. Cheers!